# Select various positions of nodes in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I want to select the first element and use `@type='first'`, Last element `@type='last'`, elements between fist and last `@type='middle'`

Input:

```
<disp-quote>
  <p>Text 1</p>
  <p>Text 2</p>
  <p>Text 3</p>
  <p>Text 4</p>
</disp-quote>
```

Desired output :

```
<p type="first">Text 1</p>
<p type="middle">Text 2</p>
<p type="middle">Text 3</p>
<p type="last">Text 4</p>
```

Tried code :

```
<xsl:template match="disp-quote/p">
 <p>
   <xsl:attribute name="type">
       <xsl:value-of select="self:p/position()"/>
   </xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </p>
</xsl:template>
```

But the output is not working as expected. Please help to solve this. Thank you. I am using XSLT 2.0

Comment: I see a typo for posstion. It should be position

Comment: @PraveenHassan I sorry typing mistake. But the issue is still there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply:

```
        <p>
            <xsl:attribute name="type">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="position()=1">first</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="position()=last()">last</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>middle</xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

**you can try this choose when condition**

```
<xsl:template match="disp-quote/p">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="not(preceding-sibling::p)">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'first'"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="not(following-sibling::p)">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'last'"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="'middle'"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```